# Fade in / out javascript with jquery doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fade in and out different `<div>` on my site. The div´s together are all one form. In every `<div>` I have a "go further" and a "go back" button. A go further button triggers this script:

```
  document.getElementById("addnewjob_sitetwo").onclick = function(){

            // Fade out all content 

            $('#newjobcontent-siteone').fadeOut(200);

            function cutnewjobsitetwo(){

            //Cut all content out
            $('#newjobcontent-sitetwo').fadeIn(200);    
            $('#newjobcontent-siteone').css("display", "none");
            }
            setTimeout(cutnewjobsitetwo, 201);

            };
```

And that works. Now, if I am on `<div>` three and i want to go back to `<div>` two I have a problem.

I modified the script from above like that:

```
document.getElementById("addnewjob_sitetwo").onclick = function(){

                // Fade out all content 

                $('#newjobcontent-siteone').fadeOut(200);
                $('#newjobcontent-sitethree').fadeOut(200);

                function cutnewjobsitetwo(){

                //Cut all content out
                $('#newjobcontent-sitetwo').fadeIn(200);    
                $('#newjobcontent-siteone').css("display", "none");
                $('#newjobcontent-sitethree').css("display", "none");
                }
                setTimeout(cutnewjobsitetwo, 201);

                };
```

And that doesn´t work. The button does nothing if it gets clicked. Can anyone tell me why? I mean, the `<div>` of the first site gets faded out while it isn´t there, but is that realy the problem? - And I have to say, I`m a beginner...

Thank you

**EDIT**:

Here are some pictures. I hope it helps to understand what i want to do: [Site one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usloy.png),[Site two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoGoE.png),[Site three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYLf5.png)

So, the "weiter"-button on "Site one" triggers the same script as the "zurück"-button on "Site three". It fades out `<div>` one and three and fades in `<div>` two.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the code of the buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="addnewjob_sitetwo" id="addnewjob_sitetwo">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" style="font-size: 20px"></span>   weiter
</button>
```

This is the first and here the second:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="addnewjob_sitetwo" id="addnewjob_sitetwo" style="font-size: 20px">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-new-window" style="font-size: 20px"></span>   zurück
            </button>
```

Comment: Try hiding the element before you fade them out. So like $('#newjobcontent-sitetwo').hide();

Comment: Hi, i sadly didn´t work. - and the elements already hidden and display on "none"

Comment: You say the “weiter” and “zuruck” buttons on Site one and three both trigger the same script, can you post up the code that shows how you are doing this.

Comment: I put the code up!

Comment: Both buttons have the same id: `id="addnewjob_sitetwo"` which is invalid but will fail silently because the browser treats an id as unique. When a browser is told to look for `id="addnewjob_sitetwo"`, it will find the id then look no further because it assumes that to look for id again would be pointless since there is only one `id="addnewjob_sitetwo"`. So going forward it finds `id="addnewjob_sitetwo"` no problem, but when you ask for `id="addnewjob_sitetwo"` on the way back, it doesn't even pay attention to *zurück*, it remembers *weiter*.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you for putting light in the dark :)

Comment: Ähm, but can i trigger it thru a "class" more than one time?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have uploaded there for the third `<div>` seems to be set for the second with id
"addnewjob_site**two**" instead of "addnewjob_site**three**"

Changing:

```
document.getElementById("addnewjob_sitetwo").onclick
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("addnewjob_sitethree").onclick
```

should do the trick.

Comment: No, it is right. On div one and three it triggers the same script. That´s why it fades out div one and div three and fades in div two. The reason i do that is less code.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not understanding what you're trying to achieve here it seems. Care to reword your question to elaborate on the context?

Comment: Maybe my answer makes more sense now that you've found out that ids should be unique?